# Приложение недоступно для скачивания на "звонящие" планшеты

Tags: android, google-play

Известно, что в природе существуют планшеты-андроид с GSM-модулем (с них можно звонить).

В манифесте у меня жестко прописан запрет установки на устройства без модуля (это необходимо).

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true" />
```

Одновременно с этим, приложение не доступно для скачивания на звонящие планшеты...

Официальная документация гугла говорит о том, что необходимо для планшетов ставить "false"... Так как же тогда сделать доступным приложение для планшетов с GSM-модулем и запретить установку на устройства без модуля? Что-то гугл сам себе противоречит...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавил доступы из манифеста:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Я думаю, что проблема не в этой строчке. Покажите больше манифеста. Гугл пишет, что выставлять false нужно, чтобы можно было устанавливать на планшеты без GSM.

Comment: Да, пишет, но почему-то тыкает носом именно в эту строчку из панели разработчика... мол ставь false и будет доступно для планшетов.

Comment: видимо "планшет" по определению гугла - Android-устройство без GSM модуля

Comment: у вас никаких ограничений на размер\плотность экрана нет?

Comment: Считается, что GSM модуль там только для интернета, поэтому они не подоходят под "android.hardware.telephony". На некоторых планшетах с модулем и NetworkManager.getPhoneType() часто возвращает none

Comment: Никаких других ограничений кроме как вышеперечисленных - нет. Значит, не судьба?

Comment: А есть там вариант привилегии "доступ к сетям 3G"? А то можно было бы его включить и затребовать, а телефонию убрать.